# Drools accessing ArrayList

Tags: drools

Here i have some codes

```
class Person{
   private String firstName;
   private ArrayList<String> hobbies;

  /* setter-getter */
 }
```

I want to access all the hobbies of a particular person in drools.
ex-  (this dows not work)

```
$p: Person(firstName=="Harish")
$hobbies: ArrayList() from p.hobbies
```

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared `ArrayList<String> hobbies` it is pretty much certain that you don't have an `ArrayList` as an element of `hobbies`.

To access a field that is a list, simply bind a variable:

```
rule h1
when
   $p: Person(firstName=="Harish", $hobbies: hobbies)
then
   System.out.println( "Harish has " + $hobbies.size() + " hobbies." );
end
```

To access each of the hobbies, firing once for each:

```
rule h2
when
   $p: Person(firstName=="Harish")
   $h: String() from $p.hobbies
then
   System.out.println( "Harish has " + $h + " as a hobby." );
end
```